# Python Pycharm package requirements are not satisfied error

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, pip, pycharm

I have a python script and i want to run it on pycharm but when I try that I get error because pycharm can't include requirements to that project.

I am adding steps as a screenshot to let you know what I see.

[image: i click install requirements here]

[image: i click install here]

[image: then thats what i see]

I'm trying to solve this problem but I can't find any solution and I don't know python too much. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

As per the proposed solution from the error snapshot:

[image: proposed_solution]

you need to [upgrade the pip version](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installation/#upgrading-pip) first using the following command:

```
$ python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```